# Binary search algorithm to maximize values

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search, greedy

I was assigned this problem I have to solve:

There are plenty of guided activities in a certain swimming pool. Therefore, the usage rules are very strict:

The free time slots are only one minute long. After using a free slot, we must wait for at least x seconds before using another slot. You have the list of free slots, and you want to swim for at least `m` minutes. What is the maximum `x` that allows it?

Input

Input consists of several cases. Every case begins with the number of minutes `m` and the number of slots `n`, followed by `n` triples `H:M:S`, indicating that there is a lane that is free for one minute starting at `H:M:S`. Assume `2 ≤ m ≤ n ≤ 1000`, that the hours are between `00:00:00` and `23:59:00`, and that there are no overlaps between time slots. The final entry is marked with a special case with `m = n = 0`.

Output

For every case, print the maximum `x` that permits a total bath time of m or more minutes.

**What would be a possible implementation using binary search over the variable x to maximize it?**

Outputs of the problem:

```
input: 
4 8 
00:10:40 00:35:30 01:00:00 01:55:00 02:10:00 03:15:00 12:00:20 23:59:00 
output: x = 11000
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the details of a "problem i have to solve", with the entire world. Now, what is your question?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I would like to know a possible implementation to maximize the variable x of the problem using binary search.

Comment: There are many possible implementations. Too broad.

Comment: Please - be fair and delete this! People end up here because you placed "binary search" in your question and this helps ZERO! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't require any search at all. Transform the list from free time-slots to a list of waiting-time between timeslots in seconds (take into account you're swimming for one minute):

```
waiting_time[]

for i in [1, length(time_slots))
   waiting_time[i - 1] = delta_minutes(time_slots[i - 1], time_slots[i]) * 60 - 60
```

Sort the list of waiting-times

```
sortDesc(waiting_time)
```

Since you've got to wait `m - 1` times, `x` must be chosen such that at least `x` waiting-times are at least equally long. Since we're searching for the maximum `x`, the smallest waiting-time must be exactly as long as `x`, which is the `m - 1`th element in our array.

Putting it all together:

```
minX(input[], m):
     waiting_time[]

     for i in [1, length(input)):
         waiting_time[i - 1] = delta_minutes(time_slots[i - 1], time_slots[i]) * 60 - 60

     sortDesc(waiting_time)

     return waiting_time[m - 1]
```

Comment: admittedly the question was very broad, but it was tagged `C++` not `python`.

Comment: @m8mble well, this is pseudocode, not python. I'm willing to present a solution to your problem, but I won't write the full code for you.